# Is there a way to have the actual document(s) inserted in place of the file name(s)?

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to have the uploaded files included in the PDF. Currently only the name of the file is included.

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded images are included in [merged documents](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/document-merging) in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), but not other file types.